# Read Access violation string pointer

Tags: c, pointers, access-violation

I'm trying to run this function, to print the indexes of char within a string.
while it runs for the first index of a string and prints the index, after incrementing the string pointer by 1 (to continue reading the string from where it left) it throws me out with the message :

"Access violation reading location 0x00000000066FF2E9." when it returns to the while loop for the second time.

I've done this type of thing before and it worked, what am I missing?
I don't think I've exceeded the string length with the pointer so there shouldn't be a problem from what I know...
very thankful for any help!

```
void printIndexesOfChar(char* string, char findIndex)
{
char* temp = string;
  while(strlen(temp) > 0)   
  {
      printf("%s \n", temp);                //prints what is left of the string to check
      temp = strchr(temp, findIndex);       //get pointer to the char we are looking for to calculate index

      if (temp != NULL)                     //if strchr didn't return NULL
      {
          printf("the char %c is located at index %d\n\n", findIndex, (temp - string));   //prints index
          temp++;                           //continue the string after the char index we found in the next iteration
      }
      else
      {
          break;                            //exits while if no more chars in the string
      }
  }
}
```

the main :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHARS_STR 40
void main()
{
        char str[MAX_CHARS_STR];
        char indexChar;

        printf("\nProgram 3 Selected.\n\nPlease enter a string of characters for the indexes to be shown.\n");
        scanf("%s", str);
        printf("\nType which character index to print:");
        indexChar = getche();
        printf("\n");
        printIndexesOfChar(str, indexChar);
}
```

Comment: *what am I missing?* - the calling code.

Comment: The problem might easily be in the calling code, which you failed to provide.

Comment: added the main, which calls this function.

Comment: This is unlikely to be the reson for the crash, but anyway: it is incorrect to print the result of `temp - string` as `%d`. The proper format is `%td`. Or at least explcitly cast the result ot `int`: `(int) (temp - string)`

Comment: added casting as mentioned, but the problem remains..

Comment: @Eden Dupont: What string did you enter? And what is the value of `findIndex` when you call the function?

Comment: for the string "hello" and findIndex = 'l'
the console output is:

"the char l is located at index 2"

and then the program throws to debug window with message pointing at while - 
"Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD0A2D9E80 (ucrtbased.dll) in EdenDupont.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000526FF7AB."

Comment: finally solved the problem, i did #include <string.h> in the main and not the source file where the function resides..I didn't know string.h was necessary to read partial strings..

thank you for your help

Comment: Glad you solved it. But allow me to say a few more words. Function printIndexesOfChar() still will go wrong, if the second argument is '\0'. So I suggest to change `while (strlen(temp) > 0)` into `for (; strlen(temp) > 0; temp++)`, and remove statement  `temp++;` from the loop body.  ( `for(; *temp; temp++)` is better for performance. )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  This is to limit the length of the number characters input And because the '%s' and '%[,,,]' input format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: what is the function: `getche()`.  it is not part of the standard C librarys

Comment: regarding: `indexChar = getche();`  this will probably input the newline that was still in the input stream from the call to `scanf()`  probably not what your program is really interested in.

Comment: thank you for the tips, had trouble copying the code to this interface so it didn't indent so good